# Is there any limit of file size in the Document of IOS app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to write a app to download and manage files from the web.If I just put the file in the Document. Is there any limit of file size or can I load another app to read the file in the Directory?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think there is a limit to how big a file you can put in your app’s Documents directory other than the amount of free space left on the device.

No, other apps cannot access the contents of your app’s Documents directory—that’s the entire purpose of the sandboxing system. What you can do is use the UIDocumentInteractionController class with a file you’ve downloaded to present the user with a list of apps that can handle opening that file.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem would limit the size to 4G, but im sure the iOS limits it even further.

No two apps can see each others files, unless the user export/import them via iTunes, or you set the app to be in the list of options when you hold down the link and the "Open In..." popup appears.

Check out the [UIDocumentInteractionController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

And [UIActionSheetDelegate Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActionSheetDelegate).