# Is there any limit to the capacity of an iPhone's documents folder?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any limit of file size in the Document of IOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493780/is-there-any-limit-of-file-size-in-the-document-of-ios-app)

I'm trying to save a text file in Documents folder on an iPhone. Is there a capacity limitation on this folder? Or does it just depend on the iPhone's memory capacity?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the size of your sandbox other than the remaining capacity of the device itself.

```
     To manage program memory, iPhone OS uses essentially the same virtual memory system found in Mac OS X. 
In iPhone   OS, each program still has its own virtual address space, but (unlike
Mac OS X) its usable virtual memory is  constrained by the amount of physical memory 
available. This is because iPhone OS does not write volatile pages to disk when memory
gets full. Instead, the virtual memory system frees up volatile memory, 
as needed, to make sure the running application has the space it needs. It does 
this by removing memory pages that are not being used and that contain read-only contents,
such as code pages. Such pages can always be loaded back into memory later if they are needed again.

     If memory continues to be constrained, the system may also send notifications to 
the running applications, asking them to free up additional memory. All applications 
should respond to this notification and do their part to help relieve the memory pressure. 
For information on how to handle such notifications in your application, see 
“Observing Low-Memory Warnings.”
```

Comment: Unkown Thank you for the valuable information. I'll take this into my consideration while making my app!

Comment: It's been more than a year ago since you answered my question. Thank you for responding quickly. I was forced to get away from the programming and did not check in the Stack Overflow. My apologies for the late reply. I think I will be able to ask questions now again!